# Move file with specific extension from a directory hierarchy to a destination

Tags: macos, command-line, automation

I have a directory hierarchy containing many images with `.jpg` file-extension, and there are multiple folders containing these images. There are many `.json` files as well in these folders.

Is there a way to scan all these subfolders and move the `.jpg` files to a specific destination/folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create and open your destination folder.

Go to the base directory you want to scan in Finder. In the search field, enter kind:jpg. Select JPEG image when it shows up.

After it generates a list of all the JPEG images, you can select them all with Command-A and drag them to a folder. If you hold down ALT when you drop them on the folder, you'll get a copy instead of a move.

Comment: This is a much nicer idea than having to use command-line for it. Thanks!

Comment: I figured there was a reason why you're asking in the "Mac" exchange instead of the Unix/Linux exchange.I can sed and awk with the best of them, but I buy Macs because I don't WANT to remember cryptic regular expressions and commands.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a command-line solution, use the following:

```
find /source_root_directory_path -name '*.jpg' -exec mv {} /target_directory_path \;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will be sure to check this out as well.

Comment: I see two issues with your `find` _command_. The first is fine if one does not want `.JPG` as well as `.jpg` files moved, `-name '*.jpg'` should be `-iname '*.jpg'` to get all JPEG files (if  that's whats really wanted). Your `mv` _command_ will overwrite any file of same name found in the _source directory structure_ when moving it to the _destination directory_. That said though, your `-exec` _command_ is better formed then mine is! :)

Comment: @user3439894 Thank you very much for pointing out and making me learn something new. I will refer to relevant manuals and amend the command to handle the cases appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

In **Terminal**, the following `bash` *compound command* will move all found `.jpg` *files* in the `"/path/to/source"` *directory* to the `"/path/to/destination/"` *directory*, but will not overwrite existing *files* at the `"/path/to/destination/"` *directory*.

```
find "/path/to/source" -iname '*.jpg' -exec sh -c 'for f in "$@"; do mv -n "$f" "/path/to/destination/"; done' sh {} +
```

After running the above `bash` *compound command*, run the following `bash` *compound command* to see what is left at the "/path/to/source"` *directory*.

```
find "/path/to/source" -iname '*.jpg'
```